# Background image is not showing up in jquery mobile page

Tags: html, css, jquery-mobile

I am using jQuery mobile. I initially tried to set a background image with `html{background: url("bg.png") repeat fixed 0 0;}` but didn't work then I tried with the body tag

```
 body {background: url("bg.png") repeat fixed 0 0;}
```

However if I define a custom class say `.myclass{background: url("bg.png") repeat fixed 0 0;}`  and then use it in my  tag then it works fine.

I am just wondering as to why the body or html tag is not working? Is it getting overridden or something? Any thoughts?

Answer (score -1):

Because of jQuery Mobile unique way of page handling you will not be able to see changes to body container. Every visible page has an greater z-index and it floats above the body.

Basically your changes to the body css are correct but they are not going to be visible.

What you want to do is change this class: **.ui-page**. That's a base class for every jQuery Mobile page.

Every custom change must override classic css with a !important.

Like this:

```
.ui-page {
    background: url('http://subtlepatterns.com/patterns/escheresque_ste.png') repeat scroll 50% 50% #112233 !important;
    color: #aabbcc !important;
}
```

Here's a working jsFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/u3E6K/